# Return an element in a list when given a list and an integer

Tags: python, function

I'm writing a function for a homework problem. The function accepts two arguments--a list and an integer. When you input the list and the integer, the function should return the element of the list that has an index corresponding with the integer.

This is some code I wrote:

```py
def find_element (sample_list, sample_integer):
   for element in sample_list:
      if index of element == sample_integer:
         return element
```

When I run this code, I keep getting a syntax error that says 'element' is undefined. I keep trying to puzzle through this and I need some help. Any input?

Comment: `index of element` isn't valid Python. It's English pseudo-code.

Comment: `index of element` how did you craft that statement? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Lists support subscription, so `L[i]` will return the element of list `L` with index `i`

Comment: Isn't it simply `sample_list[sample_integer]`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ruth https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-index/

Answer (score 1):

Python (and nearly every other language that includes arrays or lists) has a built-in mechanism for retrieving list elements by index:

```
def find_element(lst, index):
    return lst[index]
```

There's no reason to get any more complicated than that, though if you *must* count by index, you can do something like this:

```
def find_element(lst, sample_idx):
    for elem, idx in enumerate(lst):
        if idx == sample_idx:
            return elem
```

where `enumerate()` is a built-in function that returns a 2-tuple `(element, index)` for every element in an iterable like `lst`.